# Azure Function does not execute in Azure (No Error)

Tags: json, azure, queue, servicebus

I created an Azure Function App to send emails (uses service bus topics), and I have it working beautifully locally using their SDK/CLI tools, but when I publish it to Azure using the Visual Studio Publish options available, the function doesn't appear to run, there is no error, and the monitor shows "No Data Available".  The only thing I can possibly think of is that perhaps the local.settings.json file which allows me to run the app locally needs to be manually entered some place into the function app?

Clicking Run next to function.json just tells me in the Logs "2017-12-01T16:59:21  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service." no other information is presented.  Also, I checked the topic and still have messages pending.

I have verified the files did publish successfully to the bin folder using Kudo, and the function.json (below) looks right to me.  Does anyone have any ideas why this might not be triggered and isn't erroring?  As a note, the function folder only has function.json in it, but up one level the bin folder and the dll shown in the json are there.

function.json:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.0.0",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "topicName": "topicemail-dev",
      "subscriptionName": "subLowPriority",
      "accessRights": "manage",
      "name": "mySbMsg"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\Emailer.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Emailer.Functions.LowEmail"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deployed to Azure, Functions does not use `local.settings.json`. Instead, it reads values from the App Settings. All you need to do is [add App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings) values for each of the properties you have in `local.settings.json`

Comment: Thanks that did it!  Weird to me they would not at least provide some sort of error like "missing connection information" or "cannot connect"

Answer (score 0):

For people with the same issue, but who still can't get it working with the selected answer, view [Azure function implemented locally won't work in the cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952452/azure-function-implemented-locally-wont-work-in-the-cloud) , it might help.