# Azure Function with correct StorageConnectionString works locally, fails in production

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Visual Studio 2019 developed azure function (v3) that is deployed via devops pipeline when the webapp is deployed. It looks like this:

```
    [FunctionName("GetUserCoordinatesFunction")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("getusercoordinatesquery", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] GetUserCoordinatesQuery request, ILogger log)
    {
```

This function works perfectly locally. If I emulate storage, it works... if I replace my storage string with my production storage connection string, it still works.

[image]

In other words, my app writes messages to the storage without any issue.

I've double checked, triple checked, quadruple checked my AzureWebJobsStorage string in Azure Function Configuration... everything is correct!

In production only, my function "GetUserCoordinatesFunction" does not detect messages in queue. Why?
Please and thanks.

I tried this, but I'm on v3 and that didn't fix it
[Azure function implemented locally won't work in the cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952452/azure-function-implemented-locally-wont-work-in-the-cloud)

Comment: Could you please share the function.json of your function on portal ?

Comment: @HuryShen do you mean the host.json?

Comment: No, I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE0bo.png) file on azure portal.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the functions section
[screenshot](https://imgur.com/buFb0fx)

Comment: Have you deployed the function from local to azure portal ? Why it shows no functions in your screenshot ?

Comment: well, i guess that explains the issue then... I thought this would roll it out [screenshot](https://imgur.com/aweRAev)

Comment: So you haven't deploy the function success ?

Comment: Have you successfully deployed it now ? Have you solved the problem ?

Comment: This is what happens when I publish from VS 2019 [screenshot](https://imgur.com/zCI8w6p)

========== Build: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @HuryShen yes. you helped me solve this issue. Which has led to a slew of other issues.

Comment: So you solved the issue after re-deploy it to azure ? Can I post an answer below ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue with my deploy pipeline. I'm investigating that now. But after I published the function directly from VS it did show up in my functions list.

...unfortunately there is some other unrelated code that needs to be refactored before the function works as intended, but I would mark this specific post as solved for me. Yes you may post an answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize the comments above. According to the screenshot you provided, it seems the deployment didn't success. Just deploy the function from VS to azure again.